# How to store passwords in a C program for future use without writing to external file?

Tags: c, authentication, passwords, user-input

I have currently started coding an electronic journal that is password protected. The user inputs one in (when they first use the program) and then the same password can be used to access records.

**How to do this without writing the password into a file? I want the program to work every time using the same password.*?**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your requirement is quite vague. You are saying you don't even want to store the password temporarily (in a variable) while the program is running! And even though you don't want the user to input the password for subsequent access of journal, My question is if user inputs the password and you don't want to store it in variable then what is the use of prompting for password in the first place.

Comment: You can store a salted hash of the password (like in Unix [shadow file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file)) in which case it can only be cracked by trial and error, or you can use the password to [encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) the entire journal.

Comment: Ah my bad @Gaurav. I want to store the password in the program on a long term basis and the only ways I can think of right now, are: Storing in an external file or simply setting a pre-made password which the user cannot change. Just started programming recently so please bear with me haha

Comment: @NominalAnimal I'll check it out thanks.

Comment: So as per @NominalAnimal suggested you can encrypt the password and when you want to access the information where password is required you can decrypt it and supply it to the desired entity.

Comment: Actually, @Gaurav, hashing is logically very different. Although encryption works as you described, with hashing, the idea is that only the user has the plaintext password. Whatever the user supplies, is salted with the same salt as the stored hash was; and if the resulting hash matches the stored hash exactly, *then* we know the user supplied the same password as was used to calculate the original hash. In particular, with hashes, we never compare plain text passwords; only their correctly salted hashes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that standard C provides for storing data for future use is files. That is why they exist, and there is no reasonable alternative. C does not keep any of your program’s internal data from run to run. You need to use files for that.

It is not necessary to store the password itself in a file. You can store a [hash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the password. A hash is a function that converts some input, such as a string, to another value in a way such that it is hard to figure out an input that produces a specific value. Thus, if somebody learns the stored hash value, it is hard for them to figure out the password.

So, when the user sets a new password, your program would compute the hash of the password and store the hash in a file. When checking a password, your program would read a password entered by the user, compute the hash of it, and compare that hash to the one stored in the file.

Selecting, implementing, and using hash functions is a broad and complicated topic.

Comment: 100% concur. For selecting the hash, choose a slow hash, salted with a large salt. A hash like bcrypt (http://www.openwall.com/crypt/, using work factor of 12 or so), would be OK and familiar to other developers.  argon2i (https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/master/src/argon2.c) is a very solid modern choice, but may be less prevalent (and interestingly, not yet supported by hashcat, so might be harder to attack by lower-skill attackers, though John the Ripper does support attacking it).